# Elasticsearch Mapping - Multi field on nested object property

Tags: nest

I have the following property

`[Nested]
public List<TagModel> Tags { get; set; }`

and in the `TagModel` there is a property as follows

`[String]
public string Tag { get; set; }`

I would like to map the `Tag` property as a multi field property using Nest.

I thought this would work,

```
.String
    (s => s.Name
        (n => n.Tags.First()
            .Tag)
        .Fields
            (fi => fi.String
                (sub => sub.Name("partial")
                    .Analyzer("test"))
            .String
                (sub => sub.Name("middle")
                    .Analyzer("test2"))));
```

But in the mapping it outputs, `Tags` remains as:

```
"tags": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
        "tag": {
            "type": "string"
        },
```

and then at the end of the mapping:

```
"tags.tag": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "partial": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "test",
        },
        "middle": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "test2",
        },
```

and throws a exception `400` saying `reason": "Field name [tags.tag] cannot contain '.'"`

I am guessing that it does not like the linq `First()` call in the name (which is odd as a search in a nested item does accept this....)

So how can I map a property in a class that is used in a property that is a `nested` item itself....

Currently using Nest 2.0.0 alpha-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after (alot of) guess and check, this can be done as follows:

```
x.Nested<TagModel>
    (ne => ne.Name(n => n.Tags)
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties
            (p => p.String
                    (s => s.Name(n => n.Tag)
                    .Fields
                        (fi => fi.String
                            (sub => sub.Name("partial")
                    .Analyzer("test"))
                .String
                    (sub => sub.Name("middle")
                    .Analyzer("test2"))))));
```

The `AutoMap` seems to be required when you have additional properties in the model, i.e. if I had like a `TagID` in the `TagModel` then without the `AutoMap` any additional properties not specifically mentioned here would not be mapped (even if they have the attributes etc setup).